# Compare two 2d arrays and add default rows to second array's data based on the first array

Tags: php, arrays, merge, compare, default-value

I need to compare one array of rows against another array of rows where the first array will have all possible identifiers (`track_name`) represented and the second array may or may not have all identifiers represented as rows.

Upon comparing the rows between the two arrays, I need to add rows to the second array to make sure all identifiers are represented and if adding a new row, its default `gross_total` must be set to `0`.

How can I combine the two arrays and add zero default `gross_total` rows?

Sample input:

```
$saved_royalties = [
    [
        'gross_total' => 1.797,
        'track_name' => 'Desert Dance',
        'transaction_type' => 'S'
    ],
    [
        'gross_total' => 0.0678,
        'track_name' => 'Memphis City Of Kings',
        'transaction_type' => 'AS'
    ],
    [
        'gross_total' => 0.023,
        'track_name' => 'North African Market',
        'transaction_type' => 'MT'
    ],
    [
        'gross_total' => 0.1173,
        'track_name' => 'The Oracle',
        'transaction_type' => 'CL'
    ]
];
```

and

```
$matching_royalty_rows = [
    [
        'gross_total' => 2.435174,
        'track_name' => 'Desert Dance',
        'transaction_type' => 'S'
    ],
    [
        'gross_total' => 0.336815,
        'track_name' => 'Memphis City Of Kings',
        'transaction_type' => 'AS'
    ],
    [
        'gross_total' => 0.214106,
        'track_name' => 'The Oracle',
        'transaction_type' => 'CL'
    ]
];
```

My current code:

```
$combined_rows = [];
    foreach($saved_royalties as $key => $value) {
        if(isset($matching_royalty_rows[$key])) 
        {
            $combined_rows[$key]['gross_total'] = $matching_royalty_rows[$key]['total'];
            $combined_rows[$key]['track_name'] = $matching_royalty_rows[$key]['track_name'];
            $combined_rows[$key]['transaction_type'] = $matching_royalty_rows[$key]['transaction_type'];
        } else {
            $combined_rows[$key]['gross_total'] = 0;
            $combined_rows[$key]['track_name'] = $saved_royalties[$key]['track_name'];
            $combined_rows[$key]['transaction_type'] = $saved_royalties[$key]['transaction_type'];
        }
    }
```

but this is comparing on first level indexes.  How can I compare the rows by `track_name`?

Desired output:

```
[
    [
        'gross_total' => 2.435174,
        'track_name' => 'Desert Dance',
        'transaction_type' => 'S'
    ],
    [
        'gross_total' => 0.336815,
        'track_name' => 'Memphis City Of Kings',
        'transaction_type' => 'AS'
    ],
    [
        'gross_total' => 0,
        'track_name' => 'North African Market',
        'transaction_type' => 'MT'
    ],
    [
        'gross_total' => 0.214106,
        'track_name' => 'The Oracle',
        'transaction_type' => 'CL'
    ]
]
```

I can get both of the code blocks below to work when there are only unique `track_name` with unique `transaction_type`. I am running into problems where there is the same `track_name` with a different `transaction_type`. here is an example that has different `transaction_type` for the same `track_name`:

$saved_royalties:

```
array ( 0 => array ( 'gross_total' => 1.8825, 'track_name' => 'A Real Good One', 'transaction_type' => 'NR', ), 1 => array ( 'gross_total' => 1.8163, 'track_name' => 'A Real Good One', 'transaction_type' => 'S', ), 2 => array ( 'gross_total' => 0.0312, 'track_name' => 'Full Album', 'transaction_type' => 'SB', ), 3 => array ( 'gross_total' => 0.7, 'track_name' => 'Shade Tree Mechanic', 'transaction_type' => 'DT', ), 4 => array ( 'gross_total' => 0.04, 'track_name' => 'Shade Tree Mechanic', 'transaction_type' => 'O', ), 5 => array ( 'gross_total' => 0.38, 'track_name' => 'Shade Tree Mechanic', 'transaction_type' => 'PR', ), )
```

$matching_royalty_rows:

```
array ( 0 => array ( 'gross_total' => 1.078894, 'track_name' => 'A Real Good One', 'transaction_type' => 'NR', ), 1 => array ( 'gross_total' => 2.611135, 'track_name' => 'A Real Good One', 'transaction_type' => 'S', ), 2 => array ( 'gross_total' => 0.031244, 'track_name' => 'Full Album', 'transaction_type' => 'SB', ), 3 => array ( 'gross_total' => 3.4147, 'track_name' => 'Shade Tree Mechanic', 'transaction_type' => 'DT', ), )
```

using the first solution of the first answer I get:

```
array ( 0 => array ( 'gross_total' => 2.611135, 'track_name' => 'A Real Good One', 'transaction_type' => 'S', ), 1 => array ( 'gross_total' => 2.611135, 'track_name' => 'A Real Good One', 'transaction_type' => 'S', ), 2 => array ( 'gross_total' => 0.031244, 'track_name' => 'Full Album', 'transaction_type' => 'SB', ), 3 => array ( 'gross_total' => 3.4147, 'track_name' => 'Shade Tree Mechanic', 'transaction_type' => 'DT', ), 4 => array ( 'gross_total' => 3.4147, 'track_name' => 'Shade Tree Mechanic', 'transaction_type' => 'DT', ), 5 => array ( 'gross_total' => 3.4147, 'track_name' => 'Shade Tree Mechanic', 'transaction_type' => 'DT', ), )
```

using the second solution of the first answer I get:

```
array ( 0 => array ( 'gross_total' => 1.078894, 'track_name' => 'A Real Good One', 'transaction_type' => 'NR', ), 1 => array ( 'gross_total' => 2.611135, 'track_name' => 'A Real Good One', 'transaction_type' => 'S', ), 2 => array ( 'gross_total' => 0.031244, 'track_name' => 'Full Album', 'transaction_type' => 'SB', ), 3 => array ( 'gross_total' => 3.4147, 'track_name' => 'Shade Tree Mechanic', 'transaction_type' => 'DT', ), )
```

the desired output is:

```
array ( 0 => array ( 'gross_total' => 1.078894, 'track_name' => 'A Real Good One', 'transaction_type' => 'NR', ), 1 => array ( 'gross_total' => 2.611135, 'track_name' => 'A Real Good One', 'transaction_type' => 'S', ), 2 => array ( 'gross_total' => 0.031244, 'track_name' => 'Full Album', 'transaction_type' => 'SB', ), 3 => array ( 'gross_total' => 3.4147, 'track_name' => 'Shade Tree Mechanic', 'transaction_type' => 'DT', ), 4 => array ( 'gross_total' => 0, 'track_name' => 'Shade Tree Mechanic', 'transaction_type' => 'O', ), 5 => array ( 'gross_total' => 0, 'track_name' => 'Shade Tree Mechanic', 'transaction_type' => 'PR', ), )
```

using the first solution of the first answer, I've tried a few ways adding in `transaction_type`:

```
$lookup_trans_type =  array_column($matching_royalty_rows, null, 'transaction_type');
```

and then use the variable in the foreach loop below it. The farthest I could get was the correct order and values for `track_name` and `transaction_type`, but all the `gross_total` were 0.

in the second solution of the first answer I didn't make much progress. I tried adding `transaction_type` :

```
fn($a, $b) => $a['track_name']['transaction_type'] <=> $b['track_name']['transaction_type']
```

I tried a few variations of that idea without much success.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the two arrays on a value-to-value basis with `array_udiff()` or you can generate a lookup array and make key comparisons.  If your data sets are relatively small there will be no noticeable difference in performance and you can choose either technique based on what you are comfortable with / understand best.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/cJV09))

```
$diff = array_udiff(
    $saved_royalties,
    $matching_royalty_rows,
    fn($a, $b) => $a['track_name'] <=> $b['track_name']
);

$combined_rows = $matching_royalty_rows;
foreach ($diff as $row) {
    $row['gross_total'] = 0;
    $combined_rows[] = $row;
}
var_export($combined_rows);
```

---

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/t4MaX))

```
$lookup = array_column($matching_royalty_rows, null, 'track_name');

$combined_rows = [];
foreach ($saved_royalties as $row) {
    if (isset($lookup[$row['track_name']])) {
        $row = $lookup[$row['track_name']];
    } else {
        $row['gross_total'] = 0;
    }
    $combined_rows[] = $row;
}
var_export($combined_rows);
```